# Why do I not need to address a return type of Page Object?

Tags: java, selenium, return-type, pageobjects

I am a little puzzled at the moment.. This question may be more of a java question rather than a selenium question but I do not understand this. Lately, my team and I have been passing off the following page objects in our tests like so. We would have a method that would have a **return type of a page object**

```
public MyAtcMyCarsPage clickManageSavedCarAlerts(){
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(manageSavedCarAlerts).click();
        return new MyAtcMyCarsPage(driver);
    }
```

now in our test script we would instantiate all of our page object using the testng @BeforeClass

```
homePage = new HomePage(driver);
footerPage = new FooterPage(driver);
```

and so on.. Now here is the part I dont understand.. If I was going to use the method above, clickManageSavedCarAlerts(), I would do..

```
myAtcMyCarsPage = alertPage.clickManageSavedCarAlerts();
```

by doing this I am addressing the return type of a MyAtcMyCarsPage.. However, the following also works as well..

```
alertPage.clickManageSavedCarAlerts();
```

This runs fine, no errors. I am ignoring the fact that the method itself has a return type of a page object. Why is this? Are certain return types able to be ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always ignore the return value of a method.  It's not just specific types, it's everything.

If you don't assign it to a variable, the method gets run and the result gets discarded.

Comment: Wow.. something so small but I never knew that. Thank you!